# How can I style normal html tables (or ASP tables) like the rest of the RadGrid in my website?

Tags: asp.net, radgrid, html-table

I'd like to have a normal table to look like RadGrids, is there an easy way I can use the RadGrid styles (keeping theming in mind)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a tool like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/1843/), you can inspect the table generated by RadGrid.

The example shown on [this page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/draganddrop/defaultcs.aspx) gives the following results:

```
<table class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells">
   <thead>
     <th class="rgHeader" scope="col">header</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <td class="rgRow">cell</td>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Adding the classes stated here to your own table should copy the style from the rad grid.

Comment: I've added your snippet as is to my page, but it does not seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not without a link to your page. The classnames might differ per version.

Comment: I had to add a div with another style, see my own answer in this thread. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with this, and it seems you need to wrap the table in div(s) with certain styles - maybe due to themes? Maybe I'm still missing something, but this is the only way I could get it to work.

```
<div class="RadGrid RadGrid_Sunset">
    <table class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells">
        <thead>
            <th class="rgHeader" scope="col">header</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <td class="rgRow">cell</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```